# Extend an external application's menu

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, menu

I am currently writing a plugin for a third party application. 
As the plugin framework does not provide any way to access the UI I am now trying to do this manually via the WinAPI.

More specifically, I want to add a custom menu item for my plugin in the "File" menu.

My first attempt using *FindWindow* to retrieve the handle of the main window and the using *GetMenu* was not successful, as *GetMenu* simply returned NULL.

My next step was to use *EnumChildWindows* and search for a child having the text "&File" (I really don't like this approach as it makes localization quite terrible). However, I only found out the handle of the menu item, but I need the corresponding *HMENU* to use AppendMenu then, don't I? 
Simply casting does not work and results in an "Invalid menu handle".

Is it actually possible to achieve what I am trying? How?

Thanks for your ideas in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It more than likely just isn't a HMENU.  Custom menu implementations are common, the one Window provides is dated and inflexible.  Compare to Windows Forms' MenuStrip for example.

Of course, that blows a gaping hole in your approach.

Comment: But Winsharp only needs it to work on this specific application (that his plugin is written for) so if he can make this method work why not?

Comment: Hmm - I understand. If it is a custom menu - do you have any ideas how it might be implemented (it looks like a OS themed menu)? Maybe I am able to hook the creation of the menu popup itself...

Comment: Hooking the popup might work to get a handle, but you still don't have any way to *add* an item.  These won't be MENUINFOs.  Anything goes as far as possible implementations, study the dependencies and look at the EXE internals to try to discover a class library that might have been used.

Comment: Maybe this won't be necessary: I hooked into the WndProc of the application's window and waited for WM_MENUSELECT whose lParam contains a handle to the menu being opened. I used AppendMenu passing that handle and finally my menu item is visible (not in the menu I want it to have but I hopefully will manage to place it where I want). Now I will try if I can solve the problem and try to react to the user clicking my menu item.

Comment: There is still one big problem: WM_MENUSELECT is only sent when the user moves over the first menu entry - when opening the menu for the first time, my entry won't be visible. For the "File" menu WM_INITMENU does not seem to be triggered. WM_INITMENU could be the solution but I don't receive this message. Any ideas why?